# Properties of Covariance (Matrix and Vector Case)

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, covariance-matrix

In 1 dimensional case, we have $Cov(cX_1,X_1) = cCov(X_1,X_1).$ Here $X_1$ is just a random variable.

I was wondering if we have an analogue for $Cov(AX_1,X_1)$, where $A$ is a matrix with appropriate dimensions for the multiplication. And, $X_1$ here is a random vector.

Thanks in advance for any helpful insights.

Comment: I assume you know that in the univariate case $Cov( X_1, X_1) = Var(X_1)$

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is an analogue $$\mathcal{Cov}(A X_1, X_1) = A \, \mathcal{Cov}(X_1, X_1) \,,$$
it is just a particular case of property (4) in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-covariance_matrix. It can be shown by noting that the matrix factorizes out of the expectation value used to define the covariance.